# Site collection not created programmatically only in LIVE Server

Tags: 2007, development, error, site-collection, site

I am using SharePoint 2007 and was not able to create site collection and add sites pro grammatically using c#  code.

Some times it creates the site collection and some times it doesn't.

works fine for local server...but for LIVE SERVER site collection not created

Can any one describe me the possible causes for this.

Comment: Paste the code the creates the site collection?

Comment: Please also look in the ULS logs for any clues.

Comment: Hi Falak, I have pasted the code below....

Answer (score 0):

```
        SPWebApplication spwebApplication = null ;

        SPWeb web = null;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            string newSiteUrl = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(GetSharepointURL()))
            {
                spwebApplication = spSite.WebApplication;
                if (spwebApplication != null)
                {
                    //FormDigestSettings to disable security validation settings for this code only.
                    spwebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
                    var siteCollections = spwebApplication.Sites;
                    if (siteCollections != null)
                        using (SPSite newSite = siteCollections.Add(string.Format("Sites/{0}", journalId), shortname, journalname, 1033, "STS#1"
                         , Frontiers.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteCollectionOwner"], Frontiers.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteCollectionOwnerName"], string.Empty))
                        {
                            newSiteUrl = newSite.Url;
                            if (newSite.AllWebs.Count > 0)
                            {
                                 web = newSite.AllWebs[0];
                                if (web != null)
                                {
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                    Guid id = web.Lists.Add("Articles Library", "Articles Library", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                                    // web.Lists.U
                                    if (id != null)
                                    {
                                        web.Update();
                                        SPList list = web.Lists[id];
                                        list.EnableVersioning = true;
                                        list.OnQuickLaunch = true;
                                        list.Fields.Add("DocumentType", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                                        SetFieldProperties(list.Fields["DocumentType"]);
                                        list.Fields.Add("FileFormat", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                                        SetFieldProperties(list.Fields["FileFormat"]);
                                        list.Fields.Add("DocumentId", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                                        SetFieldProperties(list.Fields["DocumentId"]);
                                        list.Fields.Add("TitleName", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                                        SetFieldProperties(list.Fields["TitleName"]);
                                        list.Fields.Add("StageName", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                                        SetFieldProperties(list.Fields["StageName"]);
                                        list.Fields.Add("IsDeleted", SPFieldType.Boolean, false);
                                        SetFieldProperties(list.Fields["IsDeleted"]);
                                        list.Fields["IsDeleted"].DefaultValue = "0";
                                        list.Fields["IsDeleted"].Update();
                                        list.Fields.Add("Checked Out To", SPFieldType.User, false);
                                        SetFieldProperties(list.Fields["Checked Out To"]);
                                        //   list.Fields[0].ShowInDisplayForm
                                        SPView defaultView = list.DefaultView;
                                        defaultView.ViewFields.Add("DocumentType");
                                        defaultView.ViewFields.Add("FileFormat");
                                        defaultView.ViewFields.Add("DocumentId");
                                        defaultView.ViewFields.Add("TitleName");
                                        defaultView.ViewFields.Add("StageName");
                                        defaultView.ViewFields.Add("IsDeleted");
                                        defaultView.ViewFields.Add("Checked Out To");
                                        defaultView.Update();
                                        list.Update();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            flag = true;
                        }
                }
               }

            }});
```